# Populate object with detail from another object

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I got two item:

*List:*

```
[{
  "key": "A",
  ...optionalAprops
}, {
  "key": "C",
  ...optionalCProps
}]
```

*Collection:*

```
{
  "A": {
    ...detailAprops
  },
  "B": {
    ...detailBprops
  },
  "C": {
    ...detailCprops
  }
}
```

How to, using Ramda.js or functional style, populate *List* with details from *Collection*, mapped by its **key**?
The result should be like

```
[{
  "key": "A",
  ...optionalAprops,
  ...detailAprops
}, {
  "key": "C",
  ...optionalCprops,
  ...detailCprops
}]
```

What I have now is

```
var populate = R.curry(function(coll, item) {
  return R.merge(item, R.props(R.props('key', item), coll));
});

var result = R.map(populate(Collection))(List);
```

The `populate` function looks very un-functional to me as it still passes states around. Is there any cleaner way to achieve the same task, using Ramda.js? 
The step breakdown is

- Iterate *List* item
- Take `key` in the item
- Find detail object in *Collection* with `key`
- merge back to the item

Comment: does your solution work or is your question only about the "look"?

Comment: it works, but I'm wondering if there's any "functional" way of doing the same task, without having to pass state around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to keep the state just where you want it is to move the `map` call inside your function:

```
var populate = R.curry(function(coll, list) {
  return R.map(function(item) {
    return R.merge(item, R.prop(R.prop('key', item), coll))
  }, list);
});

populate(Collection, List); 
// or `populate(Collection)` to create a function that accepts a List
```

(Note that I replaced `R.props` with `R.prop`. I assume this was just a typo; otherwise you include all sorts of presumably unwanted keys.)

There might be some way to make this points-free, but it would probably end up being uglier.  Perhaps not; I haven't tried.  But I see points-free as useful only when it makes the code more readable.  I doubt it would here.

Also note how much ES6 arrow functions help clean this up:

```
var populate = R.curry((coll, list) => R.map(
  item => R.merge(item, R.prop(R.prop('key', item), coll)
), list));
```

You can see all this in the **[Ramda REPL](http://bit.ly/1KaGOWW)**

### Update

I did want to see what this would look like in a points-free style.  As I suspected, this is not nearly as clean as the original solution, and far less so than the ES6 version, but it's not quite as bad as I feared:

```
var populate = R.curry(R.useWith(
  R.map, 
  R.flip(R.converge(
    R.merge, 
    R.identity, 
    R.useWith(R.prop, R.prop('key'))
  )), 
  R.identity
));
```

Note the heavy use of two of Ramda's oddball functions, [`useWith`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith) and [`converge`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge).  These are alternate styles of functional composition that often turn out quite useful.

You can see the steps of how I converted one to another in the **[REPL](http://tinyurl.com/olmxevy)**.

Comment: Thanks! The point-free solution, though not easy to understand, the creative usage of `useWith` and `converge` is really brilliant. Guess point-free have it's limitations, will stick with non-point-free one when there's no easy point-free solution.

Comment: Definitely not brilliant.  You can examine the [steps of that conversion](http://tinyurl.com/olmxevy) and note that it's simply fairly mechanical steps all trying to get the parameters into the right spots to eliminate the points.  But it does help to understand those oddball composition extensions.

Comment: And I just noticed that I forgot to remove that outer `curry`, which is [no longer needed](http://tinyurl.com/q5ebpss) because the `useWith` directly inside already curries.  So it could be a little cleaner.